# Grid vs Box: when to use which ? - MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I have the following question which I believe is quite valid.

So Box and Grid are Layout components which you are suppose to add other components inside those as far as I'm aware. However sometimes Box does the job for me and sometimes is Grid and SOMETIMES I use both at same time.

This question came to mind to me after I was trying to CENTER a component, so in this example when I use GRID I can center the component in the middle of the screen without any issues:

Grid Example:

[ExampleA-Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-frog-3lsdo?file=/src/App.js:888-889)

Box Example:

[ExampleB-Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-sound-nn713?file=/src/App.js)

I know I can just simply add pl={number} to the box component and then I can move the box to a desire location but that's not the point.

Comment: `Box` is **not** a layout component. It provides access to CSS utilities (via the `sx` prop), but by default all it renders is a `<div>`.

Comment: Well, on the Layout section you can see Box, Container, Grid, etc

Comment: I am not sure why you are asking this kind of question. A Grid is just for grid while a Box is just a div but simply make flexbox. Why do you use grid and flexbox in normal cases without Material UI? Answer to your own question.

Comment: I have started with MUI I don't know much about the "normal cases" without mui

Comment: Then please learn about grid and flexbox before you getting into Material UI.

Comment: Right, question still unanswered though when to use Grid vs Box. Is a valid question for the community, just saying.

Comment: @ReactPotato `Box` can be used for layout, but the only layout capabilities it provides are via the CSS utilities. To know how to center something using `Box`, you need to know how to center it using CSS.

Comment: I see thanks for that @RyanCogswell

Answer (score 0):

The difference between Grid and Box components in Material UI:

**Box component**: The Box component functions similarly to a  tag, you can set it as any other component by defining "component" attribute with different values eg "div, section,button..." and it will act as a valid HTML tag.

**Grid component**: is used in order to create a layout on your page,
when defining Grid component you must set "Grid container" (parent component) and in it pass "Grid item" (child component), your page will be divided on a 12-column grid layout that by defining in it different **Box** components and based on size screen you provided content will be displayed in different way.
As a frontend developer using MUI i really like to use Grid component in order to create responsive web designs.

**Conclusion:** if you want to create layout for whole page use **Grid**, if you want to add content to your page eg (inside Grid) use **Box**

See links below for more information:

- [MUI Grid](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/)
- [MUI Box](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-box/)